# MySQL: Getting the results of these two subselects in one

Tags: mysql, subquery

I searched a lot, but did not find a fitting answer, and after trying for several hours its time to ask someone who knows :)

Ok, This is the Query its about (all unneccessary content stripped):

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `details`,
    `tour_type_id`,
    `meeting_point_id`,
    `start_date`,
    `start_time`,
    `end_date`,
    `end_time`,
    `max_guests`,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(`level`)
        FROM
            `tour_notification`
        WHERE
            `model_id` = `tour`.`id`
                AND `deactivated` != 1) `notification_level`,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(`level`)
        FROM
            `guide_notification`
        WHERE
            (`tour1_id` = `tour`.`id`
                OR `tour2_id` = `tour`.`id`)
                AND `deactivated` != 1) `guide_notification_level`
FROM
    `tour`
```

What I did not succeed in was to get the 2 MAX(`level`) in one:
Get the MAX from  `notification_level` and `guide_notification_level`.
I do not need these values seperately, I just did not succeed getting in in one.

My best attempt was the following approach:

```
     (SELECT 
            MAX(`level`)
        FROM
        (SELECT `level` FROM
            `tour_notification`
        WHERE
            `model_id` = `tour`.`id`
                AND `deactivated` != 1 UNION DISTINCT SELECT `level`
        FROM
            `guide_notification`
        WHERE
            (`tour1_id` = `tour`.`id`
                OR `tour2_id` = `tour`.`id`)
                AND `deactivated` != 1) as `notifications`) `notification_level`,
```

but here MySQL complained:
ERROR: Error 1054: Unknown column 'tour.id' in 'where clause'

If I add the tour table into the where clause of these subselects, it always gets the results for any items of tour table, not just the current one.

Anyone can push me in the right direction?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the problem with the first query that it returns 2 columns for the levels instead of 1? If so, you could add or concatenate the two sub-queries. Your 2nd query doesn't make sense syntactically. A SELECT can have only 1 FROM clause and 1 WHERE clause. A subquery can only return a single value. It might work better to set up joins in a single query without the subqueries and use a group by.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work for you. It provides three different ways of combining the levels into one column. Remove the ones you do not want.

```
SELECT 
    a.`id`,
    a.`name`,
    a.`details`,
    a.`tour_type_id`,
    a.`meeting_point_id`,
    a.`start_date`,
    a.`start_time`,
    a.`end_date`,
    a.`end_time`,
    a.`max_guests`,
    a.`tour_level`,
    a.`guide_level`,
    CONCAT(`tour_level`," ",`guide_level`) as `notification_level1`,
    a.`tour_level` + a.`guide_level` as `notification_level2`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.`tour_level`," ",a.`guide_level`) as `notification_level3`
FROM `tour` a
LEFT JOIN `tour_notification` b
ON a.`id` = b.`model_id` AND b.`deactivated` <> 1
LEFT JOIN `guide_notification` c
ON a.`id` = c.`tour2_id` AND c.`deactivated` <> 1
GROUP BY a.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the **greatest** value of two, you can use the `GRATEST()` function. But I think a UNION ALL subquery with `LIMIT 1` would be more readable:

```
(
    SELECT MAX(`level`) AS `max_level`
    FROM `tour_notification`
    WHERE `model_id` = `tour`.`id`
      AND `deactivated` != 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MAX(`level`) AS `max_level`
    FROM `guide_notification`
    WHERE (`tour1_id` = `tour`.`id` OR `tour2_id` = `tour`.`id`)
      AND `deactivated` != 1
    ORDER BY max_level DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS `notification_level`
```